# JNAでC++から文字列を受け取る

Tags: java, c++

JNAを用いてJavaからC++のライブラリの関数を使い、戻り値としてfloatとStringの配列を得たいのですが、floatは全く違う値になり、Stringは読み出そうとするとSIGSEGVが発生します。関数の呼び出しや、引数に与えた構造体がC++側で読めていることは確認しています。[このサイト](http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/example14.html)などを参考に以下のようなコードを作成しています。どうすればエラーなく処理できるでしょうか？

c++

```
typedef struct result {
    float* score;
    char** value;
} result;

result myfunc(){
    result *res = (result)malloc(sizeof(result));
    memset(res, 0, sizeof(result));

    (*res).score = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 10);
    memset((*res).score, 0, sizeof(float) * 10);
    (*res).value = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        (*res).score[i] = getscore(i);

        char* val = getvalue(i);
        (*res).value[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(val));
        memset((*res).value[i], 0, sizeof(val));
        strcpy((*res).value[i], val);
    }
  /* ここでres.score[i], res.value[i]を出力すると正常な値になっているのを確認 */
}
```

java

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.*;

public interface MyLib extends Library {
    public static class result extends Structure {
        public static class ByValue extends result implements Structure.ByValue {}
        public Pointer value; // char**
        public Pointer score; // float*
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[]{
                    "value", "score",
            });
        }
    }

    MyLib INSTANCE = (MyLib) Native.loadLibrary("mylib", MyLib.class);
    public result.ByValue myfunc();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyLib.result.ByValue res = MyLib.INSTANCE.myfunc();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        float score = res.score.getFloat(i * Native.getNativeSize(Float.TYPE));
        System.out.println(score); // 値が異なる
    }

    String[] strs = res.value.getStringArray(0, 10);// SIGSEGVが発生
    for (String s: strs){
        if(s != null){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(result)malloc` は `(result*)malloc` であるべきです。（ここに投稿する時に単なるtypoで間違った？） また`myfunc` は、値を返していませんけど？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

リンク先のサンプルのは、Cの構造体配列をそのままJavaから得る場合のサンプルです。
Java から安全に参照可能な構造体配列を取るのであれば、自分でインスタンスを作らなければなりません。例えば String の配列であれば以下の通り。

```
ret= (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(3,
     env->FindClass("java/lang/String"),
     env->NewStringUTF(""));
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret, i, env->NewStringUTF("こんにちわ世界"));  
}
```

これをご自分の構造体をクラスとしてwrapした物で置き換えると出来上がるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。result構造体のscoreとvalueをそれぞれjobjectArrayにしてresult構造体を返す感じでしょうか。jni.hが現状そのままではインポートできないので、そこも含めてやってみます。

Comment: いえ、result 構造体を Java 側に用意します。
まず scope と value を持っているクラス(例: com.example.Foo とします。出来れば getter/setter あり)を Java 側で作り、それを javah に通して wrapper を作ります。そして上記の NewObjectArray の第二引数に  "com/example/Foo" を指定し、NewStringUTF の代わりに NewObject を指定します。もちろん NewObject の後にそのオブジェクトに渡すべき scope value の設定が必要です。

Comment: なるほど理解しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

C++ myfunc()のコード見ただけですが気になったところ

```
(*res).value[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(val));
```

これだと 「char *」のサイズ分しか確保できてないので getvalue() の戻り値次第ですがstrcpy()実行時にバッファーオーバフローを起こしてる気がします。

```
(*res).value[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(val)+1));
```

Comment: `祈`という文字(UTF-8: E7A588)で`sizeof(val)`が8、`sizeof(char)*(strlen(val)+1)`が4でした。4が正しいと思いますので反映します。ありがとうございます。